# Passing arrays to operations/functions in Q# Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: programming, q#

In order to pass inputs to Q# operations/functions with Jupyter Notebooks, one uses the magic command, `%simulate`, and writes out the inputs as key-value pairs, `key=value`.

For example, if I had some operation, operation `HelloHardy (number : Int) : Unit {...}`, then I would run the following `%simulate HelloHardy number=1729`.

I am currently working with the operation, `EvaluatePolynomial`, which is part of the numerics library and takes in integers, arrays of doubles, and booleans. Below is what I am running and the error message that is generated.

```
%simulate EvaluatePolynomial coefficients=[1.0,1.0] evaluationPoints=[0.0,1.0] numBits=3 pointPos=3 odd=true even=false.

Received invalid parameters. Please fix and try again:

 coefficients: Error converting value "[1.0,1.0]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Double]'. Path '', line 1, position 11.

 evaluationPoints: Error converting value "[0.0,1.0]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Double]'. Path '', line 1, position 11.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IQ# magics don't support passing arrays as parameters at the moment. When I need to pass something more complicated than a scalar, I usually define a wrapper operation that defines all parameters and calls the original operation, and call `%simulate` for that wrapper operation.